# Chart.JS plugin, draw after animation

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to write a chart.js (v.2.7) plugin to show errorbars on my scatter / line plots.
I managed to get the pixel positions from the chart and draw the errorbars on the canvas, but i cannot get the timing to look right. I want them to appear after the lines animate, then stay attached (& move with) if the datasets are hidden->shown.

I've tried:

- The `afterDraw` / `afterDataset(s)Draw` / `beforeDraw` hooks: the error bars are already on the plot before the lines animate (as in example). When hidden->shown, the error bars are in place.
- `afterRender` / `afterEvent` hook: draws them after the animation finishes, but then redraws them everytime the datasets are hidden->shown (after a pause)
- `beforeRender` / any earlier hooks: gives no errorbars
- `setTimout()` on the draw function, or at various places inside it: does nothing
- `sleep()` before the draw function or other places: slows down the whole animation but the errorsbars are unaffected.
- I couldn't find a way to invoke plugin functions after animation or get to then via the `options.animation.onComplete`

**Is there a way to get the errorbars to behave as in the example, but the initial appearance occurs after the line animation (with a plugin?)**

```js
   var errorbarPlugin = {

 calcPoints: function(chartInstance, dataList){
  var ds = chartInstance.data.datasets
      var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(0)
        var yScale = chartInstance.scales[meta.yAxisID];
      var xScale = chartInstance.scales[meta.xAxisID];
      
      
  var yList = []; var xList = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++){
              
    var yValue = dataList[i].y
    var yPixel = yScale.getPixelForValue(yValue)
    yList.push(yPixel)
                
    var xValue = dataList[i].x
    var xPixel = xScale.getPixelForValue(xValue)
    xList.push(xPixel)
   }
      
  return {yList: yList, xList: xList}
 },

 calcErrorbars: function(chartInstance, ds_num){
  var ds = chartInstance.data.datasets
   var data_list = ds[ds_num].data
      
   var isHidden = ds[ds_num]._meta[Object.keys(chartInstance.data.datasets[ds_num]._meta)[0]].hidden;
   var yList = this.calcPoints(chartInstance, data_list).yList
   var xList = this.calcPoints(chartInstance, data_list).xList
   if(ds[ds_num].errors){
    var errors = ds[ds_num].errors
   } else {errors = 0}
      
  return [xList, yList, errors, isHidden]
 },


 drawErrorbars: function(chartInstance){
  var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx
  var ds = chartInstance.data.datasets
          
  for(var ds_num = 0; ds_num < ds.length; ds_num++){
   var errCalc = this.calcErrorbars(chartInstance, ds_num)
   
   var isHidden = errCalc[3]
   var yList = errCalc[1]
   var xList = errCalc[0]
   var errors = errCalc[2]
   var errWidth = 3
   var capLen = 5

   if(!isHidden){
    for(var k = 0; k < xList.length; k++){
     
                  ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
                      ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.moveTo(xList[k], yList[k]-errors[k]);
                  ctx.lineTo(xList[k], yList[k]+errors[k]);
                  ctx.moveTo(xList[k]-capLen, yList[k]+errors[k]);
                  ctx.lineTo(xList[k]+capLen, yList[k]+errors[k]);
                  ctx.moveTo(xList[k]-capLen, yList[k]-errors[k]);
                  ctx.lineTo(xList[k]+capLen, yList[k]-errors[k]);
                  ctx.stroke()
     
    }
   }
  }
 },

 afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance) {
  this.drawErrorbars(chartInstance)
  },

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/charts/errorbarPlugin3.js' %}"></script>

 <div id="canvas-holder" class="col-sm-3">
  <canvas id="chart-gamma" width="200" height="200"/></canvas>
 </div>

<script defer>
var gammaChartData = {
 datasets: [
  {
  label: 'Red',
  data: [{x: 15, y: 30}, {x: 35, y: 17}, {x: 55, y: 37}, {x: 72, y: 45},],
  borderColor: "red",
  errors: [10, 28, 30, 34],
  },
 ]
 }

var ctx_gamma = document.getElementById("chart-gamma").getContext("2d");

 window.onload = function() {
 var gamma_chart = new Chart(ctx_gamma, {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: gammaChartData,
  plugins: [errorbarPlugin],
  options: {showLines: true},
 });
};
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Edit: shortened snippet by removing formatting and default options

Comment: i think im wanting  the same functionality

Comment: I ended up the afterDraw hook, but attaching the errorbars to the metadata instead of the data points  e,g, use chart.getDatasetMeta(), then meta.data.forEach(point, i) to attach the error bars. They now animate in with the data and disapear/reappear with it (using if !meta.hidden) if desired.

Comment: mmm interesting dont see that working but, if you say it does, could you post an update with the new 'run code snippet' so i can see it add at the correct time. I got mine to run after, but looks odd still so would like it to do it wile animating but no clear way to do this.

Comment: Here's a JSbin showing the functionality i ended up with. The errorbars can either be fixed to the data or shown independantly, and animates in / hidden / revealed with the data:  [Errorbar examples](https://output.jsbin.com/julusig/latest)  Edit: The circles are the errorbars - can do x and y errors and repesent as bars or ovals

Comment: Added it as answer below (don't want to change the question snippet, in case someone has a better method)

Comment: thanks!, perfect looks like what im after, ill deconstruct the core part when i find the energy again the amount of time i invested in this drained me a little, but by the looks of it hopefully it will work... Thanks for sharing, ill share the plugin with ya if it get it working.

Comment: i cant get it to work, i have tired with chart.getDatasetMeta(), then meta.data.forEach(point, i)  could you assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315554/chartjs-how-to-apply-after-animation

Comment: I added an answer there too. I can't remember how I found out how to do it, but it took a lot of trial and error! If it's useful, could you accept / upvote (and this answer too? :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with (snippet below)

The errorbars can either be fixed to the data or shown independantly, and animate in / are hidden / revealed with the data.

The plugin can add x  or y axis errors, repesented as bars (with/without caps) or ovals / circles (filled or transparent).

```js
"use strict";
var errorbarPlugin = {
    afterDraw: function (chart) {
        var type = chart.config.type;
        var plugConfig = chart.config.options.errorbarPlugin;
        if (plugConfig) {
            if (plugConfig.showErrors) {
                var showErrors = plugConfig.showErrors;
            }
        }
        else
            showErrors = true;
        if (showErrors !== false) {
            if (["line", "scatter"].includes(type)) {
                errorbarPlugin.scatterErrorbars(chart);
            }
            else if (type == "bar") {
                console.log("Bar charts not supported yet");
            }
        }
    },
    scatterErrorbars: function (chart) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;
        var plugConfig = chart.config.options.errorbarPlugin;
        chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            var ds = dataset;
            var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
            var showErrors;
            (ds.showErrors === false) ? showErrors = false : showErrors = true;
            var errWidth;
            (ds.errWidth) ? errWidth = ds.errWidth : errWidth = 1;
            var showCap;
            (ds.showCap) ? showCap = ds.showCap : showCap = true;
            var capLen;
            (ds.capLen) ? capLen = ds.capLen : capLen = 3;
            var errStyle;
            (ds.errStyle) ? errStyle = ds.errStyle : errStyle = "T";
            var errFillColor;
            (ds.errFillColor) ? errFillColor = ds.errFillColor : errFillColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            if (!meta.hidden && showErrors) {
                meta.data.forEach(function (element, index) {
                    var x_point = element._model.x;
                    var y_point = element._model.y;
                    var errColor;
                    (ds.errColor) ? errColor = ds.errColor : errColor = element._view.borderColor;
                    var dataPoint = ds.data[index];
                    var yError;
                    var xError;
                    if (typeof (dataPoint) === "object" && 'r' in dataPoint) {
                        yError = dataPoint.r;
                    }
                    else if (ds.errors) {
                        yError = ds.errors[index];
                    }
                    else {
                        yError = null;
                    }
                    if (typeof (dataPoint) === "object" && dataPoint.e) {
                        xError = dataPoint.e;
                    }
                    else if (ds.xErrors) {
                        xError = ds.xErrors[index];
                    }
                    else {
                        xError = null;
                    }
                    var position = element.tooltipPosition();
                    if (errStyle == "circle") {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(position.x, position.y, yError, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                        if (ds.hidden === true && meta.hidden === null) {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
                            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
                        }
                        else {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = errColor;
                            ctx.fillStyle = errFillColor;
                        }
                        console.log(meta.hidden);
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                    else if (errStyle == "oval" || errStyle == "ellipse") {
                        if (xError) {
                            var scaleFac = (xError) / yError;
                        }
                        else
                            scaleFac = 10 / yError;
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.scale(scaleFac, 1);
                        ctx.arc(position.x / scaleFac, position.y, yError, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                        ctx.restore();
                        if (ds.hidden === true && meta.hidden === null) {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
                        }
                        else {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = errColor;
                        }
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                    else {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(position.x, position.y - yError);
                        ctx.lineTo(position.x, position.y + yError);
                        if (xError) {
                            ctx.moveTo(position.x - xError, position.y);
                            ctx.lineTo(position.x + xError, position.y);
                        }
                        if (ds.hidden === true && meta.hidden === null) {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
                        }
                        else {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = errColor;
                        }
                        ctx.stroke();
                        if (showCap) {
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(position.x - capLen, position.y - yError);
                            ctx.lineTo(position.x + capLen, position.y - yError);
                            ctx.moveTo(position.x - capLen, position.y + yError);
                            ctx.lineTo(position.x + capLen, position.y + yError);
                            if (xError) {
                                ctx.moveTo(position.x - xError, position.y - capLen);
                                ctx.lineTo(position.x - xError, position.y + capLen);
                                ctx.moveTo(position.x + xError, position.y - capLen);
                                ctx.lineTo(position.x + xError, position.y + capLen);
                            }
                            ctx.stroke();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js'></script>



<body>
 
<div style = "position:relative;
    width:60%;"      >

 <div id="canvas-holder" class="col-sm-6">
  <canvas id="chart-gamma" width="500" height="500"/></canvas>
 </div>

  <div id="canvas-holderbf2" class="col-sm-6">
   <canvas id="chart-humid" width="500" height="500"/></canvas>
  </div>

<script defer>

Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = true
Chart.defaults.global.legend.position = 'right'
// Chart.defaults.global.legend.onHover = function(){}
// Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = function(){}
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.usePointStyle = true
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.fontsize = 12
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.padding = 10

var gammaChartData = {
 datasets: [
  {
  label: 'Eu',
  data: [{x: 5, y: 45}, {x: 10, y: 100}, {x: 25, y: 120}, {x: 50, y: 125}, {x: 100, y: 150}, {x: 120, y: 250},],
  borderColor: "red",
  //fillColor: "pink",
  errors: [15, 20, 30, 12, 10, 10],
  xErrors: [3, 7, 16, 12, 12, 30, 10],
  //hidden: true,
  errColor: "blue",
  errStyle: "circle",
  errFillColor: "pink",
  hidden: true,
  errWidth: 2,
  showCap: true,
  capLen: 3,
  showErrors: true,
  },
  {
  label: 'Am',
  data: [{x: 15, y: 85, r: 14}, {x: 25, y: 37, r: 8}, {x: 62, y: 135, r: 44},],
  borderColor: "blue",
  errColor: "red",
  errStyle: "circle",
  showErrors: true,
  },
 ]

 }
var options_gamma = {
 animation: {
  duration: 1000,
 },
 errorbarPlugin: {
     showErrors: true,
     marginsOfError: [100, 50, 10],
 },
 elements: {
  line: { fill: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  point: { radius: 0,
    pointStyle: 'circle',
    borderWidth: 1,
    hitRadius: 18, //size if should hover
    // hoverBorderWidth: 13,
    hoverRadius: 10, //size when hovered
  },
 },
 annotation: {
  annotations: [{
    id: 'h-line-01', // optional
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'horizontal',
    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
    value: '125',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderDash: [2, 2],
    borderWidth: 2,
    label: {
      enabled: true,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)', // Background color of label, default below
      //fontFamily: "sans-serif", // Font family of text, inherits from global
      fontStyle: "normal", // Font style of text, default "bold"
      fontSize: 12, // Font size of text, inherits from global
      fontColor: "red",// Font color of text, default below
      xPadding: 5,// Padding of label to add top/bottom, default below
      yPadding: 5,// Radius of label rectangle, default below
      cornerRadius: 10, // Anchor position of label on line, can be one of: top, bottom, left, right, center. Default below.
      position: "left", // Adjustment along x-axis (left-right) of label relative to above number (can be negative)
           // For horizontal lines positioned left or right, negative values move the label toward the edge, and negative values toward the center.
      xAdjust: 290,   // Adjustment along y-axis (top-bottom) of label relative to above number (can be negative)
           // For vertical lines positioned top or bottom, negative values move the label toward the edge, and negative values toward the center.
      yAdjust: 0,   // Whether the label is enabled and should be displayed
       // Text to display in label - default is null
      content: "Max"
     },
     onClick: function(e) { // Fires when the user clicks this annotation on the chart (be sure to enable the event in the events array below).
     }
  }],
 },
 responsive: true,
 showLines: true,
 hoverMode: 'single', // should always use single for a scatter chart
 legend: {},
 scales: {
  yAxes: [{
   display: true,
   position: 'left',
   id: 'y-axis-0',
   ticks: {min: 0,  //beginAtZero:true,
     max: 200,
     //display: true,
     //fontColor: "black"
   },
   scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Number'},
   gridLines: {color: "black",
      //display: true,
      drawOnChartArea: false,
      zeroLineColor: "black",
      //drawTicks: true,
   },
  }],
  xAxes: [{
   display: true,
   type: 'linear',
   id: 'x-axis-0',
   position: 'bottom',
   ticks: {min: 0,
     max: 100,
     //display: true,
     //fontColor: "black",
   },
   scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Volume'},
   gridLines: {color: "black",
      zeroLineColor: "black",
      drawOnChartArea: false,
   },
  }],
 },
}
var ctx_gamma = document.getElementById("chart-gamma").getContext("2d");

var humidChartData = {
 datasets: [
  {
  label: 'B errors',
  data: [{x: 5, y: 45}, {x: 10, y: 100}, {x: 25, y: 120}, {x: 50, y: 125}, {x: 100, y: 150}, {x: 120, y: 250},],
  borderColor: "green",
  errors: [15, 20, 30, 12, 10, 10],
  xErrors: [3, 7, 16, 12, 12, 30, 10],
  errStyle: "oval",
  showLine: false,
  errColor: "border",
  //pointBackgroundColor: "white",
  //pointBordercolor: "white",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  hidden: true,
  errWidth: 2,
  showCap: true,
  capLen: 3,
  radius: 0,
  showErrors: true,
  },
  {
   label: 'B trend',
   data: [{x: 5, y: 45}, {x: 10, y: 100}, {x: 25, y: 120}, {x: 50, y: 125}, {x: 100, y: 150}, {x: 120, y: 250},],
   borderColor: "green",
   errors: [15, 20, 30, 12, 10, 10],
   xErrors: [3, 7, 16, 12, 12, 30, 10],
   pointStyle: "line",
   showErrors: false,
  radius: 0,
  },
  {
   label: 'B data',
   data: [{x: 5, y: 45}, {x: 10, y: 100}, {x: 25, y: 120}, {x: 50, y: 125}, {x: 100, y: 150}, {x: 120, y: 250},],
   borderColor: "green",
   backgroundColor: "green",
   errors: [15, 20, 30, 12, 10, 10],
   xErrors: [3, 7, 16, 12, 12, 30, 10],
   showErrors: false,
   showLine: false,
  },
  {
  label: '',
  data: [],
  borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  },
  {
  label: 'C data',
  data: [{x: 15, y: 85, r: 14}, {x: 25, y: 37, r: 8}, {x: 62, y: 135, r: 44},],
  borderColor: "blue",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        xErrors: [3, 7, 16, 12, 12, 30, 10],
  showLine: true,
  showErrors: true,
  },
 ]

 }
var options_humid = {
 hoverMode: 'single',
 elements: {
  line: { fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  point: { radius: 3,
    pointStyle: 'circle',
    borderWidth: 1,
    hitRadius: 0,
    // hoverBorderWidth: 13,
    hoverRadius: 9,
  },
 },
 responsive: true,
 showLines: true,
 hoverMode: 'single', // should always use single for a scatter chart
 legend: {
  labels: {
   usePointStyle: true,
   // generateLabels: function() { }
  }
 },
  scales: {
   yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    position: 'left',
    id: 'y-axis-0',
    ticks: {min: 0,  //beginAtZero:true,
      max: 300 },
    scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Number'},
    gridLines: {zeroLineColor: "black", },
   }],
   xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    type: 'linear',
    id: 'x-axis-0',
    position: 'bottom',
    ticks: {min: 0,
      max: 200 },
    scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Month'},
    gridLines: {zeroLineColor: "black", },
   }],
  },
}
var ctx_humid = document.getElementById("chart-humid").getContext("2d");

window.onload = function() {
 var humidChart = new Chart(ctx_humid, {
  type: 'line',
  data: humidChartData,
  plugins: [errorbarPlugin],
  options: options_humid,
 });

 var gamma_chart = new Chart(ctx_gamma, {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: gammaChartData,
  plugins: [errorbarPlugin],
  options: options_gamma,
 });
};

</script>





</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with rendered text in

```
    plugins:[{
      afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, options) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#666666";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chart.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            ctx.fillText(Math.round(dataset.data[index]), bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
          });
        });
      }
    }]
```

To fix, inside the `meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) { ... }` loop, simply use:

```
  var position = bar.tooltipPosition();
  ctx.fillText(Math.round(dataset.data[index]), position.x, position.y);
```

(This is in @Yobmod's post, but it seems the key is to use the bar.tooltipPosition() location for the location of whatever is rendered.)